# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext with executable jar

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

Project runs fine in Eclipse running as an application. When trying to run the jar that is built by Maven I get the following error:

C:\test>java -jar SybaseTest.jar

```
C:\test>java -jar SybaseTest.jar
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

The jar file contains all of the libraries in the lib directory:
[Libraries in the jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beXjJ.jpg)

The manifest file has the library spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar in the classpath and the other 11 that are Maven dependencies.

```
Class-Path: . lib/spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-beans-4.3.2
 .RELEASE.jar lib/spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-tx-4.3.2.RE
 LEASE.jar lib/spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-aop-4.3.2.R
 ELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar lib/commons-dbcp-1
 .4.jar lib/commons-pool-1.6.jar lib/jconn4-7.0.jar lib/bcprov-jdk15on
 -1.56.jar lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

Any advice?

Comment: The libraries should not be inside the JAR... but outside of it. Place the `lib` folder on the same level as your `SybaseTest.jar`.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I put it together as if I was using Spring Boot.  Thank you.